# Do Unity bunch up similar materials automatically?

Tags: unity, performance, materials

Imagine I have `materialA` and `materialB`.

`materialB` is a direct copy of `materialA` with only a name change.

Does Unity recognize these as same materials due to their identical settings or process them as several materials?

Do they go to the GPU as bunched up(good) or solo(bad)?

Comment: With my experience trying to optimize a Unity game, I have cynical suspicions.

Comment: What do the batch numbers in the rendering statistics overlay tell you when you test this yourself? Also... why are you creating multiple identical materials in the first place?

Comment: It's a long and dumb story, in short I don't need identical materials anymore.